# flag provided but not defined: -test.v

Tags: unit-testing, go, goland

Unit test for the following code fails:

This is my main code:

```
package locprovider

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "api/domain/location"
    "api/utils/error"
    "github.com/mercadolibre/golang-restclient/rest"
)

const (
    getCountryUrl = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/countries/%s"
)

func GetCountry(countryId string) (*location.Country, *error.ApiError) {

    response := rest.Get(fmt.Sprintf(getCountryUrl, countryId))
    if response == nil || response.Response == nil {
        return nil, &error.ApiError {
            Status: http.StatusInternalServerError,
            Message: fmt.Sprintf("invalid restclient response when trying to get country %s", countryId),
        }
    }

    if response.StatusCode > 299 {
        var apiError error.ApiError
        if err := json.Unmarshal(response.Bytes(), &apiError); err != nil {
            return nil, &error.ApiError {
                Status: http.StatusInternalServerError,
                Message: fmt.Sprintf("invalid error response when getting country %s", countryId),
            }
        }
        return nil, &apiError
    }

    var result location.Country
    if err := json.Unmarshal(response.Bytes(), &result); err != nil {
        return nil, &error.ApiError {
            Status: http.StatusInternalServerError,
            Message: fmt.Sprintf("error when trying to unmarshal country data for %s", countryId),
        }
    }

    return &result, nil
}
```

This is my unit test code:

```
package locprovider

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestGetCountryRestClientError(t *testing.T) {
    // Execution:
    country, err := GetCountry("AR")

    // Validation:
    assert.Nil(t, country)
    assert.NotNil(t, err)
    assert.EqualValues(t, 500, err.Status)
    assert.EqualValues(t, "invalid restclient response when trying to get country AR", err.Message)
}
```

When I execute this unit test, I run into following error and I am not sure why it is happening.

I have few other unit tests from other go package, and they work fine without this error.

> GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.3/libexec #gosetup
>       GOPATH=/Users/abc/go-testing #gosetup
>       /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.3/libexec/bin/go test -c -o /private/var/folders/r0/f7kkkm9526lgfz6jtgtphyww0000gn/T/___TestGetCountryRestClientError_in_api_provider_locprovider api/provider/locprovider #gosetup
>       /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.3/libexec/bin/go tool test2json -t /private/var/folders/r0/f7kkkm9526lgfz6jtgtphyww0000gn/T/___TestGetCountryRestClientError_in_api_provider_locprovider -test.v -test.run ^TestGetCountryRestClientError$ #gosetup
>       flag provided but not defined: -test.v
>       Usage of /private/var/folders/r0/f7kkkm9526lgfz6jtgtphyww0000gn/T/___TestGetCountryRestClientError_in_api_provider_locprovider:
>         -mock
>   Use 'mock' flag to tell package rest that you would like to use mockups.
>   Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Did you tried to run `go test -mock`?

Comment: Using the -mock option still gives the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems similar to [golang/go issue 33869](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33869#issuecomment-525364423), which in turn pointed to [go/issue 31859 "testing: panic in Init if flag.Parse has already been called "](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31859) and this [Go 1.13 instruction](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#testing)

> Testing flags are now registered in the new `Init` function, which is invoked by the generated main function for the test.
> As a result, testing flags are now only registered when running a test binary, **and packages that call `flag.Parse` during package initialization may cause tests to fail.**

As noted by [Sachin Raut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4777965/sachin-raut) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235896/flag-provided-but-not-defined-test-v/60237078#comment111645532_60237078):

> The problem seems to be with the external library ([`github.com/mercadolibre/golang-restclient/rest`](https://github.com/mercadolibre/golang-restclient/tree/master/rest)).
> As of now (July 2020), this "`golang-restclient/rest`" library does not support the latest versions of Go.
> It works well with GO VERSIONS <= 1.12

Comment: I am using go1.13.3 on darwin/amd64 platform. Do I have to downgrade my go version to fix this? What is the alternative fix for this?

Comment: @AnilJ You can test indeed if a downgrade would be enough. Again, for testing.

Comment: Downgrading the go compiler to 1.12 did help. I followed the compiler downgrade instructions from here. https://blog.notmyhostna.me/downgrade-go-installed-with-homebrew/

Comment: @AnilJ That is worrisome though, and https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31859#issuecomment-577988090 does apply: "Go has gone this long (until 1.13) telling people to put `flag.Parse()` in the `init()` and then all the sudden the behavior is silently broken"

Comment: The problem seems to be with the external library 
(github.com/mercadolibre/golang-restclient/rest)

As of now this "golang-restclient/rest" library doesn't support the latest versions of Go. It works well with GO VERSIONS <= 1.12

Comment: @SachinRaut Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.